# Two programs want a d-bus service - how can I run them both?

Tags: d-bus, screensaver, xscreensaver, light-locker

I had the following setup:

- For my screensaver, I used `xscreensaver` (because it's beautiful)
- To lock my screen, I used `light-locker` (because it's more secure then `xscreensaver`)

Recenctly, `xscreensaver` started binding to `org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver` on dbus. As a consequence, I cannot run them both anymore in parallel, cause the one I started after the other complains that `a screensaver is already running`.

I read [in the ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/D-Bus) that there is some possibility to `override` services. But it is very vague and I'm not familiar with d-bus.

Is there a way to have the two side-by-side without tampering with the source code of one of them?

For the record: unsetting the `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` environment variable before starting ether screensaver does not work.

Edit: As far as I've seen in my research, it does not seem to be possible to prevent a program to listen to a d-bus service without causing trouble to this program. If someone can confirm me this, it would make a very good answer.

Answer (score 1):

The unpleasant part of answer is that you can **try** to again run both of them in parallel, but you are most likely to face things broken. D-bus works as bus, and hence there are senders and receivers of messages with certain discipline. In case of screensaver, most likely assumed discipline is that screensaver is only one on system, and other software uses D-bus to signal whether it want to prevent invocation of screensaver or other standard function.

That said, of you want to try cowboy way and learn some D-Bus basics via trial and error, typically directory `/usr/share/dbus-1/services/` has bunch of text files named exactly after D-Bus service names with `.service` in end of name. There you **may** find also `org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver.service` file.

Be prepared that editing might break system, so you know how to revert it in case of broken system. But **here be dragons**, you try it at own risk and most likely you will break working system.

Comment: There is no `org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver.service` in `/usr/share/dbus-1/services/`. And if I look at the files located there, I feel unable to deduct how to do what I want to do. But thanks for the warnings, traveller!

Comment: xscreensaver source code on github says it keeps `.service` file as `xscreensaver-dbus.service` named - if you look at its [content](https://github.com/google/xscreensaver-dbus/blob/main/xscreensaver-dbus.service), you might recognize some lines and check whether you can deduce what to do about it.

Comment: I think the link you posted links to a project that achieved the thing `xscreensaver` does now out of the box and causes my problem. But I will look at it.